# Лицензия для документации на ПО под GNU GPL, AGPL?

Tags: документация, opensource, лицензирование

Есть некое стороннее ПО по лицензией GNU GPL или AGPL. Если писать документацию для разработчиков и вставлять туда участки кода из этого ПО, в качестве примеров, то какие ограничения для данной документации могут быть при выборе лицензии для неё?

Comment: вы документируете open source проект?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, под AGPL оный.